# Which of the following is a vector subspace of $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

To prove that $F$ is a K-vector subspace of $ E$ it suffices to prove $\alpha f_1+\beta f_2 \in F$ with $(\alpha, \beta)$ $\in K²$ and $f_1 , f_2 \in F$ .

For trivial cases and easy ones it seems straightforward. But I couldn't apply the same method for the following spaces:

$E_1 =\{(x,y,z)  \in \Bbb R^3 \mid x^2-z^2=0 \}$

$E_2 =\{(x,y,z)  \in \Bbb R^3 \mid x+y-z= x+y+z=0\}$

$E_3 =\{(x,y,z)  \in \Bbb R^3 \mid z(x^2+y^2)=0 \}$

NB: The question was "determine if these are vector subspaces of $\Bbb R^3$.  I already checked if the null element and inverses exists in these 3 cases, the usual tests to prove it's not a vector subspace, and it seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the mantra is "subspaces are defined by linear equations."

Intuition, then, tells us that $E_1$ and $E_3$ are *not* subspaces while $E_2$ is.

Of course, intuition is not the same thing as a proof so we must show why our intuition holds.

For instance, note that $(1,0,1)\in E_1$ and $(1,0,-1)\in E_1$ but
$$
(1,0,1)+(1,0,-1)=(1,0,0)\notin E_1
$$
Hence $E_1$ is not a subspace.

Also, note that $(0,0,1)\in E_3$ and $(1,1,0)\in E_3$ but
$$
(0,0,1)+(1,1,0)=(1,1,1)\notin E_3
$$
Hence $E_3$ is not a subspace.

Now, the most efficient way to directly prove that $E_2$ is a subspace one may use the [one-step vector subspace test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Vector_Subspace_Test). Can you try this?

Another quick way to see that $E_2$ is a subspace is to note that $E_2$ is the null space of the matrix
$$
A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
The null space of any $m\times n$ matrix is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$. Hence $E_2$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Oh , that gives another trick if I really understood: Find two vector for which the addition isn't stable. If so then $E$ is not a vector subspace.

The linearity is the most important feature coming with vector spaces. That was silly I didn't notice that in first place. Thank you